# Derivative Question??

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am a little confused with how I am supposed to find $g'(4)$ when given this information. I just cannot seem to find a connection if I am not given the original $f(x)$ equation. Could anyone provide some insight:

You are given:
$$
g(x)= \sqrt{x}f(x) \\
f(4)= 3 \\
f’(4)= -5 
$$

Comment: Using the product rule you can find a formula for $g'(4)$ that relies only on $f'(4)$ and $f(4)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the product-rule,

\begin{equation}
g'(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}f(x) + \sqrt{x}f'(x)
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

It helps to simply calculate $g'$ directly, even if it has to be expressed in terms of $f(x)$:
$$
g'(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^{-1/2}f(x)+\sqrt{x}f'(x) \, .
$$
Once you have done this, it becomes clear why knowing the value of $g'(4)$ does not require you to know 'the original $f(x)$ equation'—in fact, you only need to know the values of $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ when $x=4$.